# 'Attempt to dereference a past-the-end iterator' when sorting a vector of filesystem paths

Tags: c++, sorting, c++17, dereference, std-filesystem

I'm writing a simple file chooser using std::filesystem. The entries of the current directory are stored in a vector. When I try to sort the vector with std::sort the program crashes.

This happens with g++-9 on Ubuntu 19.04. The file is compiled with the -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG and -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC debug flags.

The relevant code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

struct FileBrowser {
    std::vector<fs::path> files;

    FileBrowser() {
        UpdateFiles();
    }

    void UpdateFiles() {
        files.clear();
        for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(currentPath)) {
            files.push_back(entry.path());
        }


        std::sort(files.begin(), files.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
            if (fs::is_directory(lhs) && !fs::is_directory(rhs)) {
                return 1;
            } else if (fs::is_directory(rhs) && !fs::is_directory(lhs)) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return lhs.filename().string().compare(rhs.filename().string());
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The error message looks like this:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/debug/safe_iterator.h:294:
In function:
    __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence, _Category>::reference 
    __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence, 
    _Category>::operator*() const [with _Iterator = 
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path*, 
    std::__cxx1998::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path, 
    std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path> > >; _Sequence = 
    std::__debug::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path>; _Category = 
    std::forward_iterator_tag; __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, 
    _Sequence, _Category>::reference = std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&]

Error: attempt to dereference a past-the-end iterator.

Objects involved in the operation:
    iterator "this" @ 0x0x7fff6c67d9d0 {
      type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path*, std::__cxx1998::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path> > > (mutable iterator);
      state = past-the-end;
      references sequence with type 'std::__debug::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path> >' @ 0x0x55ca5b4536c0
    }
```

I saw plenty of examples online where std::sort is called with vector.end(). I tried it with `files.end() - 1` and received the same error message.

Comment: I believe a range based for loop in that manner is undefined.
You want to create a copy first of  fs::directory_iterator(currentPath) first then put that in the loop.

Comment: `std::string::compare` returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`. both `-1` and `1` evaluate to `true`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks, that was the cause of the issue. Using the compare operator instead works without errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) requires a *strict weak ordering* comparator, as described in [[alg.sorting]/p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#3):

> [...] For algorithms other than those described in [alg.binary.search], `comp` shall induce a strict weak ordering on the values.

A strict weak ordering comparator should return `true` only if the left hand side operand precedes the right hand side operand, and `false` otherwise.

The [`std::basic_string::compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) function encodes its result as `<0`, `0` and `>0`, if the string is lexicographically less, equal or greater than the argument expression, respectively. This allows to determine the mutual relation between its arguments in a single pass. However, both positive and negative values are implicitly convertible to the `true` boolean value, and so the result will be misinterpreted by any standard library algorithm, leading to undefined behavior. In order to avoid that, the `std::sort` function call could look as follows:

```
std::sort(files.begin(), files.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    if (fs::is_directory(lhs) && !fs::is_directory(rhs)) {
        return true;
    } else if (fs::is_directory(rhs) && !fs::is_directory(lhs)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return lhs.filename().string() < rhs.filename().string();
        //                            ~^~
    }
});
```

Comment: Or, if there is some particular reason to use `compare`, the change is `return (lhs.filename().string().compare(rhs.filename().string()) < 0);`